# Visual Studio's Ctrl+tab messing up and disappearing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

So I've seen a couple of questions about Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but none of them were referring to my problem

My Visual Studio will randomly start acting funny. Sometimes, when I hit on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change tab, the navigation pane appears for half a second an disappears. If I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it'll just appear and disappear constantly, disappearing too early to even switch one tab. When it disappears it gives the keyboard focus back to whichever document I was on (so no other program actually intercepts the focus)

Then it will randomly accept my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and stay on screen once every X tries for some reason.

I double-checked my Visual Studio parameters (which have never changed) and the shortcuts are correctly set: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Window.NextDocumentWindowNav` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Window.PreviousDocumentWindowNav`. I try removing them and resetting them with no success.

Anyone ever had this problem? I don't know what is intercepting my Ctrl+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. When I restart Visual Studio, it'll work fine again for a while until at some point <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> messes up again for no reason.

Anyone ever had this bug? Any tips on how to figure out what it's from and how to fix it? I'm on Visual Studio 2013. If it's any help, I also have Resharper 8.2.1 with it

Thanks!

**EDIT**

A few extra details:

- Disabling Resharper doesn't remove the problem, still happens
- I tried setting the `NextDocumentPaneNav` shortcut to another combination, bug still happened

So basically it's not another running program catching Ctrl+tab for some reason, it's literally Visual Studio not willing to show the navigation pane for more than a micro second

Comment: If you disable Resharper, does the problem still occur?

Comment: Yes! Doesn't seem dependent to Resharper. Is there anyway I could see what exactly is catching this focus?

Comment: You can review all keyboard shortcuts in: Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and pressing the shortcut keys while in the "Press shortcut keys" field. The drop down will show everything linked to that shortcut - so double-check in case there is some context listed in addition to (Global) as this could really mess with this shortcut.

Comment: Yup, already checked that one - it's only mapped to `Window.NextDocumentWindowNav` !